# After setting the MdPaginatorIntl provider I get "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" after
I've setup the MdPaginatorIntl provider like this:

app.module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule, MdPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';
import { mdPaginatorIntlRo } from './i18l/mdPaginatorIntl';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: MdPaginatorIntl, useClass: mdPaginatorIntlRo },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

./i18l/mdPaginatorIntl.ts

```
export class mdPaginatorIntlRo {
    itemsPerPageLabel = "Comenzi per pagină";
    nextPageLabel     = "pagina anterioară";
    previousPageLabel = "pagina următoare";

    getRangeLabel(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
      if (length === 0 || pageSize === 0) {
        return `0 la ${length}`;
      }
      length = Math.max(length, 0);
      const startIndex = page * pageSize;

      const endIndex = startIndex < length ?
        Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) :
        startIndex + pageSize;
      return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} din ${length}`;
    }
}
```

If I remove this line:

```
{ provide: MdPaginatorIntl, useClass: mdPaginatorIntlRo }
```

the paginator works fine, but it's in English.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing 'changes' property according to documentation: [API reference for Angular Material paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api) . Maybe instead of rewriting whole class, extend MdPaginatorIntl:

```
export class mdPaginatorIntlRo extends MatPaginatorIntl
```